# java IDE for android

Tags: android, ide

I tried to find by myself, but failed, so maybe here someone can recommend a tool for java based projects in android 4 (not for android development, but that can run in android device)?

I found nice editor DroidEdit, but it's just editor, I was looking something more like eclipse or intellij idea - with auto complete, project files tree etc.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
- [Old 1.x JavaIDEdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.t_arn.JavaIDEdroid&feature=also_installed)
- [AIDE - Android IDE - Java, C++](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en)

suggested by SLaks